# Get value of datagrid cell with given row index and column index

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I already know proper row index and column index, but I don't know how to get value of intersection of these two.

Answer (score -5):

how about this one :
`yourDataGrid[yourDataGrid.CurrentCell.RowNumber, whateverColumnIndex];`

Comment: It gives me error: "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type "System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid".

Comment: Im sure this one will work for you now ,

dataGridView1[0, 0].Value.ToString();

Comment: take a look at this useful link 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Sorry, but I am not working with dataGridView. With DataGrid I can't use [].